# How to use google maps places autocomplete api and list suggestions in a listview and not a dropdown

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

I have used the above link, but I want the results as a list directly below the input box, not as a dropdown but as a listview occupying the whole page. Similar to Google Maps App in  Android.

How can i change the code to achieve this?